# Where can I find a Coriolis IPA in the UK?

Tags: ipa

We tried the amazing Coriolis IPA by New England Brewery during a trip to the USA. However, upon our return to the UK, we have been unable to find it anywhere.

Long shot, but has anyone ever seen/found this beer in the UK?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Seems rather difficult to find. Have you considered posting on [Beer Trade](http://www.reddit.com/r/beertrade/)?

Answer (score 4):

From their website, it looks like they only distribute around [Connecticut](http://www.newenglandbrewing.com/distributors.php).  If you are really interested in pursuing it, acheong87's recommendation of finding someone to trade with may be your best bet.